# Fetch google location history from android app

Tags: android, location-history

Well, read alot of threads about that, but didn't find real answer. Is it possible or not? If yes, how? Nothing in documentation about that, but it is not rare lately, that Google don't have documentation for 50% of it's services in current state.

Comment: Did you come up with the solution? Have same question.

Comment: Yes, It is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you plan to create something like this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.rrelmy.android.locationcachemap

Look into it sources.

Comment: Yes, but it is said that it needs root, and works only on Android < 4.x ... so this is not a solution for me, but thanx, `+1`.

Comment: I have used it on my 4.0.4

Comment: Then not sure what author ment by `DOES NOT WORK ON ICS and UP (Android 4.X), and it never will`

Comment: Just take a look into it sources